# Update result div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm making a program where I select some element in a select and I create some results via a script when a button is pressed.
The results are retrieved from the database and stored in an array. For each element in the array, I create some li elements and then append them to a div, which is shown after the button is pressed.

Here is the example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Khan1016/mkfpezy8/1/

This is a preview of the script:

```
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function () {
  $(".result").show();


  var list1= ["a","b","c"];

  var text="";

  var doc = document.getElementById("result");   
             
  for (i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    text = list1[i];
    var element = document.createElement("li");
    element.textContent = text;
    doc.appendChild(element);
  }
  list1.splice(0,list1.length);
}
```

I have tried to "reset" the array and the text, but it doesn't seem to work.
My question is, how can I update the li element when I press the button in a second time, instead of having the new li appended to the previous ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(".result").empty();` for delete content like:

```js
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function () {
  $(".result").empty();
  $(".result").show();
  var list1= [
  String.fromCharCode(97+Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)),
  String.fromCharCode(97+Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)),
  String.fromCharCode(97+Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))
  ];

  var text="";

  var doc = document.getElementById("result");   
             
  for (i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    text = list1[i];
    var element = document.createElement("li");
    element.textContent = text;
    doc.appendChild(element);
  }
  list1.splice(0,list1.length);
}
```

```css
.result {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" value="b" id="b">Button</button>
<h1>This are the results:</h1>
<div class="result" id="result"></div>
```

I add `String.fromCharCode(97+Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))` for simulate result with random letters

Comment: The "$(".result").empty();" worked, but the h1 will be hidden. What I was trying to achieve is to display the results after the button is cliked, hence without "preview". However, the solution for my case to show the h1 after the click was to create it in the script. Thank you!

Comment: exactly, create it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

use toggle for show and hide:

```
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function () {
   
        $( ".result" ).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you just need to clear the existing div `result`.
Your code is a little confusing as you are mixing native JS and jquery - really you could massively simplify it.

```
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {
  const result = $(".result");
  result.empty();
  result.show();
  ["a", "b", "c"].forEach(x => result.append(`<li>${x}</li>`));
}
```